# How to finish the data frame transpose with no duplicate values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, it looks like this:

```py
    QNumber  Supplier_name
0   0005267    BOWER CORP              
1   0005267    ROLLWAY                    
2   0005788    AIRCRAFT PRODUCTS
```

Now I want to transpose it, but not just simple transpose, I apply the groupby to help me get the following result:

```py
Merged_table.sort_values('QNumber').groupby('QNumber')['Supplier_name'].apply(lambda Merged_table: Merged_table.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().add_prefix("Supplier_name ").reset_index()

    QNumber  Supplier_name_0        Supplier_name_1         
0   0005267    BOWER CORP               ROLLWAY                                                                  
1   0005788    AIRCRAFT PRODUCTS        NaN
```

However, what I want should be this:

```py
    QNumber  Supplier_name_0        Supplier_name_1      
0   0005267    BOWER CORP               NaN                                   
1   0005267    NaN                      ROLLWAY                               
2   0005788    AIRCRAFT PRODUCTS        NaN
```

I appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to pivot the table https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
df2=df.pivot_table(index=[df.index, "QNumber"], columns=df.groupby("QNumber").cumcount(), values=["Supplier_name"], aggfunc=''.join)
#in order to reset multilevel index for columns:

df2.columns=[f"Supplier{i}" for i in range(len(df2.columns.values))]

df2.reset_index("QNumber", inplace=True)
```

And output:

```py
QNumber          Supplier0 Supplier1
0  0005267         BOWER CORP       NaN
1  0005267                NaN   ROLLWAY
2  0005788  AIRCRAFT PRODUCTS       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, I would use:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['QNumber', df.groupby('QNumber').cumcount()], append=True).unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out = df_out.reset_index(level=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   QNumber    Supplier_name_0 Supplier_name_1
0     5267         BOWER CORP             NaN
1     5267                NaN         ROLLWAY
2     5788  AIRCRAFT PRODUCTS             NaN
```